# Why does using global.gc() before creating an object prevent a negative delta in heap usage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection, child-process

I have this code, meant to be run in a child process (through `fork`, to be specific), in order to try to measure the size of an object in memory:

```
const syncComputationThatResultsInALargeObject = require('whatever');

let initMemory;
let finalMemory;
let obj;
process.on('message', () => {
  // global.gc();
  initMemory = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed;
  obj = syncComputationThatResultsInALargeObject();
  finalMemory = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed;

  process.send({
      memoryCost: finalMemory - initMemory,
  });
});
```

The reason that this is being done using a child process is to try to prevent any pollution from variables present in the parent process.

What I'm observing is, surprisingly, that sometimes the returned `memoryCost` is negative, implying that the heap size is smaller after creating `obj`.

If I however enable manual GC calls using `--expose-gc` in node, and call the GC before polling the heap usage, before creating the object, I never get negative values.

Can anyone give an answer as to why this could be happening? I'm using node 6.14.4 on Ubuntu 18.04.1, kernel 4.15.0-30-generic. Thanks.

EDIT: This happens even if I reference `obj` after the assignment to `finalMemory`, for instance, by putting a reference to one of its fields in the object passed to `process.send`.

Comment: this is just guessing, but It wouldn't be surprising if syncComputationThatResultsInALargeObject just reuses garbage memory that hasn't been collected yet, but of course after calling gc there is no such memory

Comment: A clever compiler might notice that `obj` is not accessed anywhere and garbage-collect it even before `finalMemory` is computed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more tests, I was able to understand why this was happening.

In my particular instance of the computation function, I am able to pass several parameters that influence the resulting object size.

What I ended up observing is that when repeating the computation several times for a different sets of parameters, is that parameter sets that generate a larger object present a much greater dispersion between results, even when I call `global.gc()` at the indicated line.

Thus, I am attributing the observed behavior to the fact that sometimes the GC is being called inside the computation function, in an uncontrollable manner. Greater object sizes mean greater memory usage, which means more frequent (therefore possibly unpredictable) GC calls, which means greater dispersion in results for equal parameters.

Comment: You could write `const array = []` then have `syncComputationThatResultsInALargeObject` push to the array, then clear the array after you are done measuring the heap. Would that keep the memory around to make the computation make sense?